# Java A Raw Https Request Creates Endless Redirect Loop

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, request

I try to create a raw http request:

```
GET /samplepath HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: sub.sample.net
Date: Fr., 20 Jan. 2017 12:45:39 GMT
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*\/*;q=0.8
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

What I got back is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location:  https://sub.sample.net/samplepath/
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
X-Lima-Id:  XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:  Fri, 20 Jan 2017 11:45:40 GMT
Server:  openresty
Set-Cookie:  _lcp=a; Path=/; expires=Mon Mar 20 2034 13:02:58
Connection:  close

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://sub.sample.net/samplepath/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at sub.sample.net Port 443</address>
<script type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout(function() { document.cookie = "_lcp3=a; Path=/; expires=Mon Mar 20 2034 13:02:58" }, 1000);</script></body></html>
```

I try to send the request simply over a SSLSocket from a HttpsURLConnection:

```
Socket socket = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory().createSocket(url.getHost(), url.getPort() == -1 ? 443 : url.getPort());

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("GET /samplepath HTTP/1.1");
stringBuilder.append("\r\n");
stringBuilder.append("Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n");
...
stringBuilder.append("Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\r\n");
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
wr.write(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes());
wr.close();

InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[1];
int offset = 0;
while (inputStream.read(bytesBuffer) != -1) {
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(bytesBuffer);
}
byte[] respBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
System.out.println(new String(respBytes));
```

I also try to get the SSLSocket from the Default SSLFactory and perform a startHandshake() same result.

```
socket = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(url.getHost(), url.getPort() == -1 ? 443 : url.getPort());
((SSLSocket) socket).startHandshake();
```

The problem is that the site I got redirected to the site that I requested. And if I try to request through a browser. There is no redirect. Even if I try to perform the redirect I got again a redirect back.

So what I am doing wrong here ?

Is it the init of the SSLSocket ?

Is it the change from SSLSocket to Socket ?

Have I miss something for TLS ?

Or is it a complete other Problem that I miss ?

I try figure this out the complete last month but got no solution.

**EDIT**

I also try it this way.

```
GET /samplepath HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXXX
Date: Fr., 27 Jan. 2017 22:50:39 GMT
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*\/*;q=0.8
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Now I got redirected to the landing page of the hoster. Which means that the host find the request not normal and redirect it to the landing page. In the browser I still get my normal page:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location:  http://www.lima-city.de/?utm_source=XX.XX.XX.XXX&utm_medium=webspace&utm_campaign=websites_redirect
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Pragma:  no-cache
X-Lima-Id:  XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type:  text/html
Date:  Fri, 27 Jan 2017 21:50:42 GMT
Server:  openresty
Set-Cookie:  _lcp=a; Path=/; expires=Mon Mar 20 2034 13:02:58
Connection:  close
b2
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
0
```

**SOLUTION**

Oh Man I complety take the header field **Host** wrong.
I think the header field was for the address of the client.

That is totally wrong

:-)

I dont need the other fields:

```
GET /samplepath HTTP/1.1
sub.sample.net:443
```

Now I also got the right response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<Headfields>

<Body>
```

For a one time response add Header **Connection** with the Value **close**

Comment: try using CONNECT instead of GET.  Make sure to use port 443 (if that's the SSL port the server is listening on)